# Record a copy or move that has already occurred using Subversion

Tags: svn, version-control

Mercurial provides a `-A, --after` option for moves and copies, which records those operations after they've already occurred.

How can I achieve this using Subversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So without a better answer, here's the best mechanism I've come up with:

```
# file was added
touch a
svn add a
svn ci

# file was moved without versioning
mv a b

# file versioning is added
mv b a
svn mv a b
```

Keeping in mind you can't `svn cp a b`, as `svn` will outright refuse to copy to a target that exists unless it is a directory.

Comment: Never ceases to amaze me how SVN can't cope with such basic use cases.

Comment: Moving the file back and force: Worse solution ever.

But as it seem: the only only one available. 

Answer (score 2):

You can't only record it.

What you can do is to do the copy again and overwrite the old copy target.

Comment: what do you mean by "old copy target"?

Comment: You said, the operation already occured. With "old copy target" I ment the destination of that copy operation.

Comment: Do you think you could add some command line stuff to clarify what you mean? Afaict this is the best answer, but very ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion only supports recording merges after the fact, not copies and/or moves...

Answer (score 0):

Bluntly, no, there's no way to do this in Subversion. Assuming you've made no other changes, what you probably want to do is an `svn revert` and then do an `svn copy` so Subversion knows you've copied the file. Or if you don't really care about history for a copied file, just `svn add` the new location.